# Identification help for green bases

Tags: part-identification

Recently received a batch of LEGO and it contains numerous green bases and attachments for them. I’ve never seen anything similar before. Does anyone know what they are?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.SE!  Thanks for asking this.  I picked a few of the 30489's up at a bulk purchase, but I had never figured out what they came from.  I stacked them up to make a stand for one of the Ghostbusters cars.

Answer (score 11):

Those are Sports Field Sections 8 x 16

https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30489

https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=41819c02

They appear in soccer sets

[image]

The sets are playable, you can move minifigs on springs to "shoot" the ball, or defend with the goal keeper minifig...

Comment: Here's an upvote for posting the correct answer 31 seconds before me :)

Comment: Upvote reciprocated ;)

Answer (score 6):

These belong to the [Football subtheme](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=41819c02&in=S), the parts are specificially [Sports Field Section 8 x 16 with Horizontal Slot and Black Sliding Holder, Assembly](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=41819c02&idColor=6#T=S&C=6&O=%7B%22color%22:6,%22iconly%22:0%7D) and [Sports Field Section 8 x 16](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30489#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D).

The smaller black parts are called [4142816: Chair Ø20Mm, Spring Function](https://brickset.com/parts/4142816/chair-%C3%B820mm-spring-function) and were used to have the minifigures kick the ball.